# Float rounded to Multiple then changed to string with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, floating-point, rounding

I need to round down to the nearest multiple, for a lot of pairs of numbers. And then get the result as a string (rather than scientific notation that floats output with). Considering just two, a and b, I can't seem to get it sorted out.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from decimal import Decimal
a = 0.0000026636
b = 0.000001
print(b)
print(type(b))
print(a)
print(type(a))
nearest_multiple = b * round(a/b)
print (nearest_multiple)
nearest_multiple = nearest_multiple.astype(str)
print (nearest_multiple)
c = Decimal(nearest_multiple)
print(c)
```

I don't think the rounding is going correctly, and all the outputs for float are in scientific notation.

What I want to do is input a=2343.4382, b=0.01, and output "2343.43" as a STRING value. And like a=0.123280790, b=0.0001, and get output "0.1232" as a string. Even the Decimal output has way to many sig figs.

Comment: Rob, "Considering just two, a and b," --> is `b >0` always true?  Else provide example desired output for `b < 0`. Is  `a >= 0` always true?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're just trying to truncate `a` to a precise number of decimal positions. You can do it this way:

```
a = 0.0000026636
b = 0.000001

nearest_multiple = int(a * (1/b)) / (1/b)

print(nearest_multiple)
# 2e06
```

Then you can use *Python 3.6+* formatting style to specify your decimal precision and get the float in its plain representation with the desired number of decimals:

```
nearest_multiple = f'{nearest_multiple:.{int(-math.log10(b))}f}'

print(nearest_multiple)
# '0.000002'
```

Here I used `-math.log10()` to get `b`'s reverse magnitude and use it as float precision.

Comment: Given `a = 0.299999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875` (which is representable in IEEE-754) and `b = .1`, this produces “0.3” but ought to produce “0.2”.

Comment: Given `a = .00001` (which is, when parsed, rounded to a representable value slightly over .00001) and `b = 0.00001`, this produces “0.0” but ought to produce “0.00001”.